# Clang vector extensions and the equality operator in C++

Tags: c++, clang, simd

I wrote a vector type using the Clang SIMD vector extensions. It works well, except when I need to check if two vectors are equal. The `==` operator doesn't seem to be defined correctly for Clang's vector types. Attempting to compare two vectors with `==` bizarrely seems to evaluate to a third vector of the same type as the two being compared, instead of a `bool`. I find this odd, since applying other operations like `+` or `-` compiles with no trouble, and outputs the expected results. Here's my code, compiled with Clang 3.5 (Xcode):

```
// in vect.h 
template <typename NumericType>
using vec2 = NumericType __attribute__((ext_vector_type(2))) ;

//in main.cpp
#include "vect.h"

int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {

    vec2<int> v0 {0, 1} ;
    vec2<int> v1 {0, 1} ;

    vec2<int> sumVs = v0 + v1 ; //OK: evaluates to {0, 2} when run

    bool equal = (v0 == v1) ; /* Compiler error with message: "Cannot initialize
        a variable of type 'bool' with an rvalue of type 'int __attribute__((ext_vector_type(2)))'" */

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to enable using `operator ==` with Clang's vector types, or any other workaround to this problem? Since they're considered primitive and not class types, I can't overload a comparison operator myself, and writing a global `equals()` function seems kludgy and inelegant.

**Update**: Or if no one has the solution I'm looking for, perhaps someone could explain the default behavior of the `==` operator when comparing two SIMD vectors?

**Update #2**: Hurkyl suggested `==` on two vectors does a vectorized comparison. I updated my code to test that possibility:

```
template <typename NumericType>
using vec3 = NumericType __attribute__((ext_vector_type(3))) ;

int main(int argc, const char ** argv) {

    vec3<int> v0 {1, 2, 3} ;
    vec3<int> v1 {3, 2, 1} ;

    auto compareVs = (v0 == v1) ;

    return 0;
}
```

LLDB reports the value of `compareVs` as {0, -1, 0}, which seems almost right if that's what's happening, but it seems weird that `true` would be -1, and `false` be 0.

**Update #3**: Ok, so thanks to the feedback I've gotten, I now have a better understanding of how relational and comparison operators are applied to vectors. But my basic problem remains the same. I need a simple and elegant way to check, for any two SIMD-type vectors `v1` and `v2`, whether they are equivalent. In other words, I need to be able to check that for every index `i` in `v1` and `v2`, `v1[i] == v2[i]`, expressed as a single boolean value (that is, *not* as an vector/array of `bool`). If the only answer really is a function like:

```
template <typename NumericType>
bool equals(vec2<NumericType> v1, vec2<NumericType> v2) ...
```

... then I'll accept that. But I'm hoping someone can suggest something less clumsy.

Comment: If I had to guess, `operator==` is doing a *vectorized* comparision, and thus returns a *vector* of results.

Comment: That makes sense. I modified my code slightly to test that hypothesis, I'll update my question with the results.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html or http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors and directly https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-2.0-openclc.pdf

Comment: in C/C++ when you cast an `int` to `bool` you get `false` for `0` and `true` for anything else, so the result you got in your second update is perfectly fine.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/g/QJyjDG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If instead of using the compiler-specific language extensions you use the instrinsics (as provided, for example, in `xmmintrin.h`), then you can use
`_mm_movemask_ps(__m128)` and its relatives. For example

```
__m128 a,b;
/* some code to fill a,b with integer elements */
bool a_equals_b = 15 == _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(a,b));
```

This code works as follows. First, `_mm_cmpeq_ps(a,b)` generates another `__m128` with each of the four elements to be either all bits 0 or all bits 1 – I presume `operator==` for the compiler-generated vector extensions calls exactly this intrinsic). Next, `int _mm_movemask_ps(__m128)` returns an integer with the *k*th bit set to the signbit of the *k*th element of its argument. Thus, if `a==b` for all elements, then `_mm_movemask_ps(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(a,b))` returns `1|2|4|8=15`.

I don't know the compiler-supported language extensions, but if you can obtain the underlying `__m128` (for 128 bit wide vectors), then you can use this approach (possibly only the call to `_mm_movemask_ps()`).

Answer (score 3):

Using the bitwise-complement of false as a true value isn't that unusual (see BASIC, for example).

It's particularly useful in vector arithmetic if you want to use it to implement to implement a branch-free ternary operator:

```
r = (a == c)? b: d
```

becomes

```
selector = (a == c)
r = (b & selector) | (d & ~selector)
```